# shibboleth configure with nginx and fast cgi

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, shibboleth

i'm configuring nginx with shibboleth.
This is an error I'm getting:

```
2023/05/17 13:38:08 [error] 1027193#0: *21 FastCGI sent in stderr: "shib: doHandler failed to handle the request" while reading response header from upstream, client: **.***.**, server: mydomain, request: "GET /Shibboleth.sso/ HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/etc/shibboleth/shibresponder.sock:", host: "mydomain"
2023/05/17 13:38:08 [error] 1027193#0: *21 FastCGI sent in stderr: "
" while reading response header from upstream, client: **.***.**, server: mydomain, request: "GET /Shibboleth.sso/ HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/etc/shibboleth/shibresponder.sock:", host: "mydomain"
```

Can anyone help me?